# Display data from server updated in GUI in python

Tags: python, tkinter

here's what I have in mind: I have data (numbers) in an OPC server, which I want to retrieve via a GUI. This data should be updated every 5 seconds and therefore also be displayed in the GUI. I had tried this via a while loop, which also works as print output, but then no window is displayed to me anymore.

Would there perhaps someone an idea how I can implement this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import sys
import os
import time
from opcua import Client
    

url = "opc.tcp://xxxxxxx"
client = Client(url)
client.connect()

#create main window
master = Tkinter.Tk()
print('test')
master.title("GUI Raspberry")
master.geometry("900x900")


label = Tkinter.Label(master, text='test')
label2 = Tkinter.Label(master, text='')
label.pack(padx = 5, pady = 10, side = LEFT)

while True:     
    Mean = client.get_node("ns=2;i=3")
    MeanValue = Mean.get_value()
    label2['text'] = MeanValue
    label2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 20, side = LEFT)
    print(MeanValue)
    time.sleep(5)


master.update()
time.sleep(2)

master.mainloop()
master.destroy()
```

Comment: are you aware that last four lines are never reached?

Comment: yes I am aware of that, hence my question on how to set it up differently.

Comment: It should look like something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/12118546

Comment: using `while True` in any GUI is not good idea. Most GUIs has some `timer` or other method to execute code without blocking `mainloop`. And `tkinter` has `root.after( 5000, function)` to run code after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `while True` is not good idea in any GUI. It blocks `mainloop` which gets key/mouse event from system, sends them to widgets, runs functions assigned to button and other widgets, (re)draw window and widgets.

You may need to run `while True` in separated thread - but thread can't update widgets and it would have to send result to main thread - and this makes other problems.

Or you should check if you can use `"timer"` instead of `while` to run code periodically.
All GUIs have some `"timer"` for this.
And `tkinter` has `master.after(milliseconds, function_name)`

I couldn't test it but it could looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import time
import Tkinter as tk
from opcua import Client
    
# --- functions ---

def function():
    mean = client.get_node("ns=2;i=3")  # PEP8: `lower_case_name` for variables
    mean_value = mean.get_value()       # PEP8: `lower_case_name` for variables
    label2['text'] = mean_value
    print(mean_value)
    master.after(5000, function)  # run again after 5000ms (5s)
    
# --- main ---

url = "opc.tcp://xxxxxxx"
client = Client(url)
client.connect()

# create main window  # PEP8: in comment add space after `#` (and two spaces before `#` if it is in line with code)
master = tk.Tk()
print('test')
master.title("GUI Raspberry")
master.geometry("900x900")

label1 = tk.Label(master, text='test')
label1.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side='left')

label2 = tk.Label(master, text='')
label2.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side='left')  # show it only once

function()  # run first time

master.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)